# Arduino - Vector of struct showing wrong values. How correctly fill Vector with struct?

Tags: vector, struct, arduino, scope, arduino-c++

I have some difficulties with Arduino specifically with `struct` and/or scope. I come from a Python background so I don't completely understand how things work in C/C++.

I want to define a global vector/array (I tried both) and fill it with `struct` using a function. I aim to keep the code separate and have as little as possible in the `loop()` function.

I also tried to do this using a `class`. Inside the class's function, structs have valid values, but if I create a getter and access the vector/array of `struct` outside the class they somehow hold random values.

Below is a working example in C++ of what I am trying to do in Arduino:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>


struct Remote {
    unsigned int remote_id;
};


static std::vector<Remote> remotes = {};


void setup(){
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    remotes.push_back({50});
    Remote remote = {90};
    remotes.push_back(remote);
}

void loop(){
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    std::cout<< remotes[0].remote_id <<std::endl;  // 50
    std::cout<< remotes[1].remote_id <<std::endl;  // 90
    sleep(1);
}

int main()
{
    setup();
    while (true){
        loop();
    }
    return 0;
};
```

I get this as output:

```bash
50
90
```

which is correct.

---

And my Arduino code:

```cpp
#include <Vector.h>

struct Remote {
  unsigned int remote_id;
};

static Vector<Remote> remotes = {};

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial)
        continue;

  Remote remotes_array[2];
  remotes.setStorage(remotes_array);

  remotes.push_back({50});
  Remote remote = {90};
  remotes.push_back(remote);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(remotes[0].remote_id);
  Serial.println(remotes[1].remote_id);
  delay(1000);
}
```

And here I get this output:

```bash
48386
48130
```

Why is the Arduino code printing random values as output, unlike the C++ code above which prints the expected values? Am I missing something? Should using pointers solve this issue?

Comment: `remotes_array` is a local variable which gets deleted when the function returns

Comment: Thanks @user253751 ! It works as expected! I also tried to declare this vector in a class and create a getter to this vector. Inside the class all remotes are ok but outside the class (through the getter) all remotes have random values. So, to make it work, should I need to declare the vector as global and give it to the class through the constructor ?

Comment: @AlexLaut sounds like you're probably doing something similar - using pointers to local variables which get deleted when functions return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @user253751 in the comments, the `remotes_array` is a local variable and the memory assigned to it gets deallocated after `setup()` is done. This makes the `remotes` misbehave as its memory has been "snatched" away now and the memory locations referred to by `remotes[0].remote_id` and `remotes[1].remote_id` do not belong to `remotes` anymore.

So, the correct code would be:

```c
#include <Vector.h>

struct Remote {
  unsigned int remote_id;
};

static Vector<Remote> remotes;
Remote remotes_array[2]; // --> Move memory allocating array here, outside of setup()

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
    while (!Serial)
        continue;

  remotes.setStorage(remotes_array);

  remotes.push_back({50});
  Remote remote = {90};
  remotes.push_back(remote);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(remotes[0].remote_id);
  Serial.println(remotes[1].remote_id);
  delay(1000);
}
```

This issue occurred because the `Vector` lib in Arduino is totally different from `vector` in c++ if we look at how the memory gets allocated. As [mentioned](https://github.com/janelia-arduino/Vector) by the `Vector` lib author:

> A sequence container similar to the C++ std::vector, but instead of
> allocating memory dynamically, this container points to an external,
> statically allocated c style array.